# How to create a seaborn scatterplot with multiple values per datframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I'm tiring to create a scatter plot that will have multiple points on y axis per x value. my data frame is the combination of the concatenation of multiple series so it looks like :

```
        sample 1
var A   [6.1348741][5.98921666][5.98921666]
var B   [6.06300458][6.14294531][6.14294531]
var C   [6.18084289][6.33433549 8.36140445 8.8569102 ][6.33433549 8.36140445 8.8569102 ]
var D   [6.20022251][2.99138873 6.19556828 8.36455137][2.99138873 6.19556828 8.36455137]
var E   [6.1560241][6.30790417][6.30790417]
var F   [6.17638675][6.34667509 8.74861151][6.34667509 8.74861151]
```

I've tried to use regex to extract the data but i'm only getting the first value and would anyway like to ideally treat each squire bracket list independently. anyone has any idea on how to go about it?

I would like to end up with a scatter plot that has the index on the x axis and the points on the y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the rows, and convert each string to a list of floats. Then plot those lists:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"sample 1": ['[6.1348741][5.98921666][5.98921666]',
                                     '[6.06300458][6.14294531][6.14294531]',
                                     '[6.18084289][6.33433549 8.36140445 8.8569102 ][6.33433549 8.36140445 8.8569102 ]',
                                     '[6.20022251][2.99138873 6.19556828 8.36455137][2.99138873 6.19556828 8.36455137]',
                                     '[6.1560241][6.30790417][6.30790417]',
                                     '[6.17638675][6.34667509 8.74861151][6.34667509 8.74861151]']},
                  index=['var A', 'var B', 'var C', 'var D', 'var E', 'var F'])

for idx, val in df.iterrows():
    ys = [float(v) for v in str(val[0]).replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').split()]
    plt.scatter(np.repeat(idx, len(ys)), ys, c='crimson')
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot]